# Quick proof help dealing with the intersection of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> For each real number $r \in (1, 3)$, define $A_r$ to be the interval $[0, r)$. Set $B = \bigcap A_r$.  Prove that $B = [0, 1]$.

I understand this problem up until the part where we have to set $r$ equal to the average of $x$ and $1$. Why do we need an average and is there a guideline to using averages in intersection problems like this?
Here is the part where we have to use an average:

It remains to show that $x \leq 1$. Assume to the contrary that $x > 1$.
Set $r = (1 + x)/2$, the average of $1$ and $x$.
Then $1 < r$ and $r < x < 2$; thus $r \in (1, 3)$.
Also, since $r < x$, we see that it is not the case that $x \in [0, r)$.
That is, it is not the  case that $x \in A_r$.
This contradicts the choice of $x$.
So $x \leq 1$ after all.
Thus $x \in [0, 1]$.
Therefore, $B \subseteq [0, 1]$.

Comment: It seems to me that the average was only used to ensure that $1<r<x$. I think any relationship that implied that inequality could have been used, and the average just happened to be the simplest. It's hard to tell for sure since I don't know what $x$ was defined to be.

Comment: BTW, the average will always be less than 1 and $r \notin (1,3)$ with that construction

Comment: @SalmonKiller How will the average of $1$ and $x>1$ be less than $1$?

Comment: @AMPerrine $x<1$ right?

Comment: @SalmonKiller "Assume to the contrary that $x>1$."

Comment: @AMPerrine Ah I see it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are just showing that if $x\in B$ and IF $x>1,$ then they are exhibiting there exists a number $r\in(1,3)$ such that $1<r<x.$ This implies that $x \in A_r$ for that particular $r.$  Thus $x\notin B,$ which is a contradiction.